# Git not found after installing Aptana 3

Tags: git, aptana, aptana3

I have been running git on my Mac (Mountain Lion) just fine, but after installing Aptana Studio 3, I get "git: command not found" when I try to run it from the command line now.  All the files are there under /usr/local/bin/git, and I've updated my PATH in .profile to add /usr/local (/usr/local/bin is there as well), but I still get the error when I try to run git from the command line.  Why would installing Aptana hose my git install, and how can I get it to work again? I know Aptana relies on git internally, but it shouldn't hose what's already there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/

Download and install XCODE (free) from the App Store.  Then inside XCODE install Command Line Tools.

This will fix your issue.

Alternately you can try this:

1. open your ~/.bash_profile, if you use textmate it would be:
   $ sudo mate ~/.bash_profile
   or if you use pico (built into OS X) you'd type
   $ sudo pico ~/.bash_profile
2. add this line to the file:
   export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin/
3. Save & close the file and type on the terminal:
   $ source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Yes, that is where mine is, that was what I did, that was the error I got, and that was where I had installed it from originally.

Comment: I updated my answer and I think it will help if you haven't already solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually already had XCode installed, so I just re-downloaded the git installer from http://git-scm.com/download/mac, reinstalled, and it works again.